# Potential race conditions with ConcurrentBag and multithreaded application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, design-patterns, concurrency

I've been wrestling for the past few months with how to improve a process where I'm using a DispatcherTimer to periodically check resources to see if they need to be updated/processed.  After updating the resource("Product"), move the Product to the next step in the process, etc.  The resource may or may not be available immediately.

The reason I have been struggling is two-fold.  One reason is that I want to implement this process asynchronously, since it is just synchronous at the moment.  The second reason is that I have identified the area where my implementation is stuck and it seems like not an uncommon design pattern but I have no idea how to describe it succinctly, so I can't figure out how to get a useful answer from google.

A rather important note is that I am accessing these Products via direct USB connection, so I am using LibUsbDotNet to interface with the devices.  I have made the USB connections asyncronous so I can connect to multiple Products at the same time and process an arbitrary number at once.

```
public Class Product
{
 public bool IsSoftwareUpdated = false;
 public bool IsProductInformationCorrect = false;
 public bool IsEOLProcessingCompleted = false;

 public Product(){}
 ~Product()
}

public class ProcessProduct
{
 List<Product> bagOfProducts                   = new List<Product>(new Product[10]);

 ConcurrentBag<Product> UnprocessedUnits       = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();
 ConcurrentBag<Product> CurrentlyUpdating      = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();
 ConcurrentBag<Product> CurrentlyVerifyingInfo = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();
 ConcurrentBag<Product> FinishedProcessing     = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();

 DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

 public ProcessProduct()
 {
     _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;                            //Every 1 second, call Timer_Tick
     _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);                //1 Second timer
     
     bagOfProducts.ForEach(o => UnprocessedUnits.Add(o));  //Fill the UnprocessedUnits with all products
 
     StartProcessing();
 }
 private void StartProcessing()
 {
     _timer.Start();
 }

 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ProductOrganizationHandler();

     foreach(Product prod in CurrentlyUpdating.ToList())
     {
         UpdateProcessHandler(prod);  //Async function that uses await
     }
     foreach(Product prod in CurrentlyVerifyingInfo.ToList())
     {
         VerifyingInfoHandler(prod);  //Async function that uses Await
     }
     if(FinishedProcessing.Count == bagOfProducts.Count)
     {
         _timer.Stop();  //If all items have finished processing, then stop the process
     }
 }
 
 private void ProductOrganizationHandler()
 {
     //Take(read REMOVE) Product from each ConcurrentBag  1 by 1 and moves that item to the bag that it needs to go
     //depending on which process step is finished
     //(or puts it back in the same bag if that step was not finished).
     //E.G, all items are moved from UnprocessUnits to CurrentlyUpdating or CurrentlyVerifying etc.
     //If a product is finished updating, it is moved from CurrentlyUpdating to CurrentlyVerifying or FinishedProcessing
 }
 private async void UpdateProcessHandler(Product prod)
 {
     await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
     //Does some actual work validating USB communication and then running through the USB update
 }
 private async void VerifyingInfoHandler(Product prod)
 {
     await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
     //Does actual work here and communicates with the product via USB
 }
}
```

Full Compile-ready code example available via [my code on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/f7B8t9A7).

So, my question really is this:  Are there any meaningful race conditions in this code?  Specifically, with the **ProductOrganizationHandler()** code and the looping through the ConcurrentBags in **Timer_Tick()** (since a new call to **Timer_Tick()** happens every second).  I'm sure this code works the majority of the time, but I am afraid of a hard-to-track bug later on that happens because of a rare race condition when, say, **ProductOrganizationHandler()** takes > 1 sec to run for some dumb reason.

As a secondary note:  Is this even the best design pattern for this type of process?  C# is my first OOP language and all self-taught on the job (nearly all of my job is Embedded C) so I don't have any formal experience with OOP design patterns.

My main goal is to asynchronously Update/Verify/Communicate with each device as it becomes available via USB.  Once all products in the list are finished (or a timeout), then the process finishes.  This project is in .NET 5.

**EDIT**:  For anyone that comes along later with the same question, here's what I did.

I did not understand that DispatcherTimer add Ticks to the Dispatcher **queue**.  This implies that a tick will only run if there is not already another instance of Tick already running or, worded another way, `Timer_Tick` will run to completion before the next `Timer_Tick` instance runs.

So, most(all?) of the Threading/concurrency concerns I had were unfounded and I can treat the `Timer_Tick` as a single-threaded non-concurrent function (which it is).

Also, to keep Ticks from piling up, I ran `_timer.Stop()` at the beginning of `Timer_Tick` and restarted the timer at the end of `Timer_Tick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using [DispatchTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), this will raise ticks on the UI thread. So as far as I can see there is no multi threading going on in the example. There are other timers, like `System.Timers.Timer` that raises events on a background thread if that is the intent. But if you just want to check and update status every so often, and are not running any code that blocks, just using the UI thread is fine and will simplify things a lot.

Even if we assume `ProductOrganizationHandler` did run on a worker thread, it would still be generally safe to remove items from one concurrent collection and putting them in another. But it would not guarantee that items are processed in any particular order, nor that any specific item is processed by a given tick of the timer. But since the timer will tick periodically all the items should eventually be processed. Keep in mind that most timers need to be disposed, so you need to handle that somehow, including if the processing is stopped prematurely.

Keep in mind that `async` does not mean concurrent, so I would not use it unless your USB library provides async methods. Even then I would avoid `async void` since this promotes exceptions to the captured synchronization context, potentially crashing the application, so it should mostly be used in the outermost layer, like button event handlers, or timers, and then you should probably handle exceptions somehow.

As for the best way to do it, I would take a look at [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library.

Comment: Thanks for the response... It seems that at least some of my problem stems from a misunderstanding of how DispatcherTimer actually works.  I was not aware that async void dropped exceptions.  I suppose that makes sense with the Task.Result.

Comment: Clarification:  Nearly all of my issues go away, now knowing that the DispatcherTimer does not create threads, as I thought it did.